# Specifying java heap options for OrientDb in kubernetes yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, orientdb

I am trying to specify the jvm heap options -Xmx and -Xms in the yaml file for orientdb deployment. I was able to specify other options like -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize but not -Xms and -Xmx options.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: orientdb
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    image: 
    command: [ "server.sh" ]
    args: [
      "-Dstorage.wal.path=somepath",
      "-Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=18432"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to specify it in the env part of yaml file.

```
env:
- name: ORIENTDB_OPTS_MEMORY
  value: "-Xms2g -Xmx4g"
```